# Python, error downloading scipy using pip

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, pip

I tried to download scipy using pip, but it failed.

I'm using a windows 64 machine, are there any solutions other than using anaconda?

Comment: You know, you're so much more likely to get the correct help if _you actually tell us what the error was_. :) Please see [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Download it](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) from Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows repository. You'll also need [`numpy-MKL`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) from the same place.